# Loop a Switch case

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I'm attempting to write code for a user menu. Put simply the user is given a menu of 5 options to input exam scores. Each option runs a method from a class. Once the method is done it will prompt the menu once more, and continue to loop until the user selects option 5, which will terminate the program. Though I am not sure how I can get this switch case to loop.

```
    prof1.menu();
    choice = console.nextInt();

    do
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: prof1.inputExamScore();
                break;

            case 2: prof1.modifyExam();
                break;

            case 3: prof1.displayExamScores();
                break;

            case 4: 

            case 5:

            default:
                System.out.println("That is not a valid input.");
        }
    }while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try infinite loop where you can break it from switch block as shown below:

Sample code :

```
    loop: while (true) {
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
               ...
            case 5:
                break loop;
            default:
                System.out.println("That is not a valid input.");
        }
    }
```

Hint:

- increment a counter for a valid input and break the loop if 5 is chosen after accepting all valid inputs
- move the code for accepting the user input in the loop at the beginning.